# unable to write logs to a file using log4net in an ASP.NET Web Forms Site

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net

I'm having a problem logging to a text file using log4net dll.

I'm using vs 2012 express on a windows server 2008 r2 standard (64).
 I have preform the following steps:

1. Open a new asp.net web forms
2. Install log4net via nuget manager.
3. in the global.asax file I have this in Application_Start :

   ```
   log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure ();
   ```
4. In the web config I have added to the configSections node this line :

   < section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
5. In the web config I have added this section :

   ```
   <log4net debug="true">
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="c:\webSite\extraDownloadServerResources\Logs\ALU\log.txt" />
   <appendToFile value="true" />
   <rollingStyle value="Composite"/>
   <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
   <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
   <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
   <staticLogFileName value="true" />
   <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
   <conversionPattern value="%n%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M %n - %m%n" />
   </layout>
   </appender>
   <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
     <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
   </root>
   </log4net>
   ```
6. In a start up page I have fetch instance of the logger :

   ```
   private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger ( System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod ().DeclaringType );
   ```
7. In the `Page_Load` I have wrote this line :

   log.Debug ( "test" );
8. I have add to the log.txt file security the Dedualt App Pool user with read/write permissions.

I have ended up with nothing in my log file.
To test the steps I did I have created a new empty web site and follow these steps one by one.
alas (I like this word) this time the log have been written to the file.

Can any one point me to a possible solution ?

Comment: Please update your title with your specific problem.. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: code is looking ok. Try changing file value as below line  <file value="..\ALU\\log.txt" />

Comment: Nope.that didn't work. this is an external file with no relation to the site.

Comment: Main issue here is that in the empty web site test , i did write logs to the file.

Comment: In the mean while i have tried two other things : * added requirePermission="false" to the log4net line in the configSection node. * added iisuser permission to the log file. no change.

Comment: i have tried one more thing. i have tried [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/). This too , worked well in the test site but not on my developer site. it looks like permission issue but can't put finger on where or what.

Comment: Hi I was looking very easy way to record log with log4net, so that hopefully this is useful for you please following as URL [How to use Log4net from Nuget with Visual Studio platform in the ASP.NET Web Form (Easy method)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42569713/how-to-use-log4net-from-nuget-with-visual-studio-platform-in-the-asp-net-web-for/42572770#42572770)

Answer (score 2):

To debug issues with log4net configuration you should [enable log4net internal debugging](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#internalDebug).

Inside `appSettings` add `log4net.Internal.Debug` key as following:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

This will enable log4net to output all messages to console and to the [Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx). To forward all diagnostics messages to file you can add a trace listener:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
        <listeners>
            <add      name="textWriterTraceListener" 
                type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
                initializeData="C:\tmp\log4net.txt" />
        </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

These snippets were taken directly from the [log4net FAQ](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html) and here only for quick reference.

This at least will give you understanding of what is going on as you will get error messages.

Comment: thanks.this helped me to learn one more thing about log4net capabilities,though for writing into trace file i would have the same problem without the correct user name to grant access to. i wanted to vote you up but i still don't have 15 points

Comment: @gilad You still can access trace. Either by giving everyone write permissions to `C:\tmp` folder or use Trace Viewer as described in following MSDN article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwh16c6c(v=vs.100).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

i have managed to solve my problem.

i have downloaded a [tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to monitor all iss trafic.
When monitoring the traffic i saw the user name wasn't defaultAppPool nor AppPoolName.
it was **ASP.NET v4.0**.
After i granted the permissions and restarted everything , i finally saw some logs in the file...